# Drupal 7 / Webforms: Combine Submission data from multiple webforms?

Tags: webforms

I'm working with multiple forms that have the exact same format; I need to combine the results into one result.

Is there a way to combine submission data from multiple webforms?

Comment: Combine them with what intention? Can you provide a really simple example of results for Form A and for Form B and the outcome you need.

Comment: AppName, Director, Manager, these 3 fields will be variable, the next 5 questions will all be the same on every form.  I would like to have diff forms for diff apps, but tie the forms all back into the same results.  My best bet I am thinking would be to just have completely separate forms, then just tie them all together with xls or csv after they are all completed, which wouldnt necessarily be hard, but it would be nice to get them all in the same place.

Comment: How are people being directed to the various forms? wondering if you could have a single form, but with extra in the URL depending on which version they should see, and use Conditionals to show/hide the variable fields you describe

Comment: I was just going to send multiple URLS to a group of users, maybe 20 at the most, and then mux the submissions in excel when I got them all back.